# How to save kedro dataset in azure and still have it in memory

Tags: kedro

I want to save Kedro memory dataset in azure as a file and still want to have it in memory as my pipeline will be using this later in the pipeline. Is this possible in Kedro. I tried to look at Transcoding datasets but looks like not possible. Is there any other way to acheive this?

Comment: I haven't used Azure with Kedro. Is it working for you as a dataset in the catalog? Is it just a matter of saving it *and* keeping it in memory?

Comment: yes it is working as a dataset(memory dataset) i want to save it  in azure container and at the same time other nodes want to use the memory dataset not read from azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a good opportunity to use [CachedDataSet](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.CachedDataSet.html) this allows you to wrap any other dataset, but once it's read into memory - make it available to downstream nodes without re-performing the IO operations.

Answer (score 0):

I would try explicitly saving the dataset to Azure as part of your node logic, i.e. with `catalog.save()`. Then you can feed the dataset to downstream nodes in memory using the standard node inputs and outputs.